# Redirect to a specific page from any dir or subdir in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use an universal rule to redirect to a specific page from whatever directory or subdirectory using `.htaccess`?

To be more precise, if I want to have an URL like `example.com/login` that redirects to `example.com/login.php?action=login`, I use the following line in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php?action=login [L]
```

But is it possible to to have a rule that lets me redirect from `example.com/any_directory/login` to `example.com/login.php?action=login`? So from anywhere down the `example.com` subdirectories to ``example.com/login.php?action=login`. And if yes, how can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly that is possible. Easiest is to use a rewrite condition since that operates on the absolute request path even inside a dynamic configuration file. Rewrite rules operate on a relative path i such location which makes matching complicated...

Take a look at this simple example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login$
RewriteRule ^ /login.php?action=login [L]
```

If you do the rewriting in the http servers host configuration instead you can simplify that. Reason is that it is always absolute paths the rules work on in that location:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /login$ /login.php?action=login [L]
```

The main approach in both variants is to rely on the slash preceding the login key word. It always is present in an absolute request path and clearly left-delimits the key word. And *not* to insist on matching at the line start.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your regex pattern .Simply remove the **^** ,so that it can match  anychars before **login/** in uri ie : **/foobar/login** .

```
RewriteRule /login/?$ /login.php?action=login [L]
```

Comment: @Arkascha : I understand what you are saying . /fakelogin . Sorry forgot to add a slash before the loging :D